# How do I fix function compilation error?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, sql-update

--this is my function

```
create or replace 
function sal_incr
(
p_grade number)
return number
is
v_inc number;
begin
select raise_percent into v_inc 
from sal_inc 
where grade_id in (select grade_id from emp_task where grade_id = p_grade);
return v_inc;
end;
```

-- Update statement

```
update emp_task set sal = sal + sal_incr(grade_id);
```

-- Error stack

```
Error starting at line 15 in command:
update emp_task set sal = sal + sal_incr(grade_id)
Error at Command Line:15 Column:32
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-06575: Package or function SAL_INCR is in an invalid state
06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state"
*Cause:    A SQL statement references a PL/SQL function that is in an
           invalid state. Oracle attempted to compile the function, but
           detected errors.
*Action:   Check the SQL statement and the PL/SQL function for syntax
           errors or incorrectly assigned, or missing, privileges for a
           referenced object.
```

Comment: what error do you get when you try to compile the function?

Comment: @Prabha Please make sure you format your code properly before you post, unformatted code makes it very difficult to debug and almost unreadable. I have edited your question, please do so yourself in future.

Comment: The error is clear, your function has **compilation errors** and it is in an **invalid state**. Open SQL*Plus, connect to the database, compile the function, do `SHOW ERRORS`, copy&paste the entire session by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try not to use a function at all. Using straight SQL is usually a better solution. Based on the information you gave we have the following tables. (Your function does compile with these tables.)

```
  CREATE TABLE emp_task
  (emp_id   NUMBER  PRIMARY KEY
  ,grade_id NUMBER
  ,sal NUMBER);

  CREATE TABLE sal_inc
  (grade_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  ,raise_percent NUMBER);

  INSERT INTO emp_task VALUES (1,10,1000);
  INSERT INTO emp_task VALUES (2,20,2000);

  INSERT INTO sal_inc VALUES (10, 0.1);
  INSERT INTO sal_inc VALUES (20, 0.2);
```

I've used a sub-select here (I've never done it this way before, but it works in 11g).

```
  UPDATE emp_task t1 
  SET sal = sal + sal*
    (SELECT raise_percent 
     FROM sal_inc t2 
     WHERE t2.grade_id = t1.grade_id);

  SELECT *
  FROM   emp_task;

    EMP_ID   GRADE_ID        SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10       1100 
         2         20       2400
```

You could also look at updating a view

```
UPDATE (SELECT ... FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ...
```

Or a merge statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. first think you are selecting % convert it into amount then add it.
2. check if your select query in function returns single row at each time. you can use max, min or rownum to restrict multiple rows.
3. Check if underlying table are exist in database.
4. Check data type for % is number only.
   function code look good otherwise.